# Como passar valores pra cima em uma arvores no javascript

Tags: javascript, react, algoritmo, recursão, npm

Olá, estou fazendo um exercício que consiste em fazer um algoritmo  que jogue o jogo da velha, até agora consegui gerar todos os caminhos de jogo e detectar quais levam a vitoria ou derrota e organiza os dados em um objeto de estrutura semelhante a uma arvore, o código  segue:

```js
loadPossibilities(squares, xIsNext) {
    var livres = this.getFree(squares);
    var possibilities = [];
    var Xwin = 0;
    var Owin = 0;
    var fake = squares.slice();
    var tmp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < livres.length; i++) {
      fake = squares.slice();
      fake[livres[i]] = xIsNext ? "O" : "X";
      possibilities.push({
        squares: fake,
        possibilities: [],
        Xwin: 0,
        Owin: 0,
        ganhador: calculateWinner(fake).winner
      });
      if (possibilities[i].ganhador === "X") {
        Xwin++;
      } else if (possibilities[i].ganhador === "O") {
        Owin++;
      }
    }
    if (possibilities.length > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < possibilities.length; i++) {
        if (possibilities[i].ganhador == null) {
          tmp = this.loadPossibilities(possibilities[i].squares, !xIsNext);
          possibilities[i].possibilities = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
    Xwin = Xwin = tmp.Xwin;

    Owin = Owin = tmp.Owin;
    // console.log(possibilities);
    return { possibilities: possibilities, Xwin: Xwin, Owin: Owin };
  }
```

Os valores Xwin e Owin são calculados corretamente mas quando são passados pra cima na arvore acabam se tornando undefined, a variavel squares é um vetor de nove posições que representa o tabuleiro. o codigo completo pode ser encontrado aqui https://github.com/Mathe13/tic-tac-toe-ia-2019 usei um exemplo do react como interface. alguem sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que na última execução da sua recursão o código não executará a lógica dentro do `if(possibilities.length > 1)`, portanto, a variável `tmp` não será nada mais que uma `Array` (como ela foi criada em cima assim).

Sendo assim, você não conseguirá acessar a propriedade Xwin e muito menos a Owin dela, retornando undefined para a árvore acima.